# Detect change in default values of a table ( Django )

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, frontend

**Scenario :**

I am using django to render a form, the form contains a table with multiple values. Now I want to detect if the user has changed the default values ( sent from the back-end ) and trigger an event (that changes the value of a variable say x to True or False).

**Questions:**

- Is there a way to handle this via the frontend exclusively?
- If yes,what should I look into ?

**Already looked up :**

- jquery 'change' detection ( does not work for my case as changing back to default values cant be detected )
- looping and comparison of values ( this is possible but gets ugly as the size of the table increases )
- form.changed_data ( as the data being transferred is large in size, re rendering the page with an exception will not be a choice )

Comment: did you take a look to [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)?